# Getting 2 result values every for-each iteration

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I am using a "xsl:for-each" to iterate over each element with name content and attribute that contains the text "period". When attempting to take out one date per each "xsl:for-each" iteration, it returns 2 values.

The matching of text "period" must be done like this due to the input data might change and it is unknown how many elements with id containing ="period", that would appear in the data.

I would like to keep the xpath search critera in the "xsl:for-each" syntax, because I am using the template to point out root.

When I try to subset the dates using `date[1]` it still return both dates.

[XSLT Fiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVAkJ4v/2)

**Same code as in above fiddle:**

**Data:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<section>
  <content id="period1">
      <date>2021-01-01</date>
  </content>
  <content id="period2">
      <date>2020-01-01</date>
  </content>
</section>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    >

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="/section">
    
    <xsl:for-each select="//content/@*[contains(., 'period')]">
        <date>
            <!--<xsl:value-of select="."/>-->
            <!--<xsl:value-of select="//date[1]"/>-->
            <xsl:value-of select="//content/date"/>
        </date>
    </xsl:for-each>
    
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<date>2021-01-01 2020-01-01</date>
<date>2021-01-01 2020-01-01</date>
```

**Wanted result:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<date>2021-01-01</date>
<date>2020-01-01</date>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use relative paths

```
   <xsl:for-each select="content[@*[contains(., 'period')]]">
        <date>
            <!--<xsl:value-of select="."/>-->
            <!--<xsl:value-of select="//date[1]"/>-->
            <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
        </date>
    </xsl:for-each>
```